# Jetpack Compose Android draw offscreen

Tags: android, glance

i'm quite lost on an idea i wanted to implement for Jetpack Glance. As Glance is quite limited in its functionality it thought i could draw the Image i wanted to show behind the scenes and send to my Glance/Widget to display.

For example i want that the User taps the Widget, it triggers the App to fetch some data and draw something behind the scenes and send back to the Widget to display. AFAIK this seem to be impossible to archive using compose. Regarding [this](https://shopify.engineering/lessons-building-android-widgets) post it still seems possible.

Anyone has ideas how to archive this ?